# Get the URL from webview component

Tags: xcode, webview, components

I am using the WebView component and sometimes I reload this component. But sometimes, before reloading I would like to get the URL where the WebView is still pointing.
Is it possible to get this information??

Thank you in advance.
Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UIWebView *myWebView = // ... well, we'll just say it exists.
NSLog(@"last loaded or currently loading URL: %@", myWebView.request.URL);
```

The `request` is a `NSURLRequest` object which was used to request the page so you can pretty much get anything might need out of it.